# Проблема с условиями python

Tags: python

Дана строка "Python else loop". Проверьте содержит ли она букву 'l'. Если да и следующей за ней идет одна из букв 'a', 'o', 'e', - напечатайте эти буквы. В противном случае выведите сообщения о том, что искомые комбинации не найдены.
Почему в случае с `if 'a' in  s[i+1] or 'o' in s[i+1] or 'e' in s[i+1]:` программа работает корректно, с другим `if 'a' or 'o' or 'e' in s[i+1]:`работает не корректно.

```
s = "Python else loop"

for i in range(0, len(s)):
    if 'l' in s[i]:
        print('Есть')
        if 'a' in  s[i+1] or 'o' in s[i+1] or 'e' in s[i+1]:
        #if 'a' or 'o' or 'e' in s[i+1]:
            print('Есть комбо', s[i] + s[i+1])
            break
        else:
            print('Комбо не найдены')
            break
else:
    print('l нет')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in` здесь при таком использовании не нужны, достаточно сравнения `==`

А насчёт ифа - это же питон, а не русский язык. Выполняется

```
 if 'a' or 'o'
```

это не ноль, True, дальше можно не проверять. `ls` должно вывестись, как я понимаю.

Правильно будет

```
if 'a' == s[i+1] or 'o' == s[i+1] or 'e' == s[i+1]:
```

или с использованием `in`

```
 if  s[i+1] in ['a', 'o', 's']:
```

Кроме того, диапазон цикла, чтобы не вылезти за пределы строки

```
for i in range(len(s) - 1):
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогли. Но вот насчет диапазона цикла, попробовал ваш метод, если поставить последней букву 'l', то программа ее не видит

Comment: Так если l последняя, то комбинации не может быть

Comment: Но в условии задачи, если нет комбинации, то нужно указать вывести на экран есть ли буква 'l' или нет

Comment: Ну я такого явного указания не вижу в приведённом условии. Если действительно так нужно, то при нахождении l на последнем месте не выполняйте второй if  или сделайте его таким   `if (i+1< len(s)) and  (s[i+1] in ['a', 'o', 's']):`

Comment: спасибо вам огромное)